# Laravel PHP: Display array elements in drop down list alphabetically without using sort()

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Laravel PHP Photo Gallery application that allows the user to create an album and then insert photos into an album of their choice from a drop down list.  This requires the user to create the album first since the drop down list is dynamic based on which albums actually exist.  The drop down list is currently functioning properly but it does not display albums (array elements) alphabetically.

I've tried using the **'sort()'** method but the problem is that the array element ids then become switched/re-sorted when doing so.  I do not want the array ids to be re-sorted since this will put photos into the wrong albums.

So I want to know if there is a way to display the albums alphabetically in a drop down list while not re-sorting their array element ids.

**Controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $stoneArray = $this->stone->all()->toArray();

    if (empty($stoneArray)) {
        $dropdown[0] = 'There are no stones';
    }

    foreach ($stoneArray as $stone) {
        $dropdown[$stone['stone_id']] = $stone['stone_name'];
        // sort($dropdown); /* This re-sorted the array element ids */

    }

    $data = array('type' => 'stone_photo', 'dropdown' => $dropdown);
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('forms.stones.new-photo', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('stone_id', 'Stone: ') }}
    {{ Form::select('stone_id', $dropdown, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Is `stone` a database model?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, 'stone' is a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

I'm making some assumptions here about your file structure, but it should give you the idea.

In: `app\Acme\repositories\Eloquent\EloquentStoneRepository.php` or whatever you called it, there's a function:

```
public function all()
{
  return Stone::all();
}
```

(I think that's what it looks like, but I'm not positive). Try changing that to:

```
public function all()
{
  return Stone::orderBy('column_name', 'asc')->get();
}
```

If you use `all()` somewhere else and don't want it sorted, consider adding another function:

```
public function all_sorted()
{
  return Stone::orderBy('column_name', 'asc')->get();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Edit:
Changed `->all()` to `->get()` so eloquent can properly sort it.

Comment: After using your suggestion, I'm getting a 'Call to undefined method Acme\repositories\Eloquent\EloquentStoneRepository::orderBy()' error.

Comment: So `stone` is actually a repository, making an edit.

Comment: Sorry you're right, Stone is a repository.  After using your suggestion by changing my 'all()' function, I'm getting the error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()'.  Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Nvm try: `Stone::orderBy('column_name', 'asc')->get();

Comment: I was looking up how to sort Eloquent repository lists and your last solution was mentioned for using the 'orderBy()' method.  Tested it and works fine now!  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Really helped me out a lot!